# How to upgrade database Sonarqube running on Windows

Tags: database, service, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am trying to [upgrade](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) `SonarQube` from version `4.4` to version `5.1` and I keep running into problems on `Windows` 64-bit.

4.4 is currently running on 9000 and I'm pretty sure I've changed the `wrapper` and `sonar` conf files correctly.

Can someone tell me the correct steps to upgrade this correctly or point me in the right direction?

I am getting this error in the logs about upgrading the database:

> Impossible to upgrade database
>
> Migration failed: com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream . Please check
>   logs.

```
  Migration failed: com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream .
2015.06.15 15:46:09 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to upgrade database
com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream
    org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.xml.FindBugsFilter.createXStream(FindBugsFilter.java:157)
    org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsProfileImporter.importProfile(FindbugsProfileImporter.java:54)
    org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.SonarWayWithFindbugsProfile.createProfile(SonarWayWithFindbugsProfile.java:43)
    org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RegisterQualityProfiles.profilesByLanguage(RegisterQualityProfiles.java:182)
    org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RegisterQualityProfiles.start(RegisterQualityProfiles.java:91)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
    org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
    org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents$1.doPrivileged(ServerComponents.java:851)
    org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:43)
    org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.executeStartupTasks(ServerComponents.java:847)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:126)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:122)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
    org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
    org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
    org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

(I'm a coder, not an IT architect. Sorry for the naivety)

Comment: You linked to the upgrade steps yourself.  Can you be more specific about what the problems are?

Comment: @ioscode I've the error I'm getting in the log. I wasn't sure if the instructions were different for Windows

Comment: Ok, posting that information is helpful.  I'm not familiar with that error, but hopefully now that people have more to go on, more help will arrive.

Comment: Which versions of plugins are installed (see extensions/plugins/) ? And what is your JDK ?

Comment: I'm currently facing the same issue on Linux while upgrading from 4.2 to 5.1.1. It seems to be an issue with the FindBugs plugin while it attempts to import the FindBugs quality profile. You should have a findbugs plugin under extensions/plugins. I'm taking a look at the code to understand why it fails while it tries to create the XStream object; which it will then use to actually read in the xml. Will let you know if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to upgrade SonarQube.

1. Stop the SonarQube server
2. Download and unzip the new SonarQube distribution in a fresh directory, let's say NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME.
3. Update the content of the sonar.properties and wrapper.conf files located in the NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME/conf directory with the content of the related files in the OLD_SONARQUBE_HOME/conf directory (web server URL, database settings, etc.). Do not copy-paste the old files.
4. Copy the OLD_SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins directory into NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins.
   (warning) Check the Compatibility Matrix for plugins compatibility and manually upgrade the plugins if necessary: . 
   5.If a custom JDBC driver is used, copy it into NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/jdbc-driver/.
   (warning) Back up your database.
   (warning) If an es directory exists under data, remove the es directory (such a directory should not exist if step 3, above, was followed).
5. Start the web server
6. Browse to http://localhost:9000/setup (replace "localhost:9000" by your own URL) and follow the setup instructions.
7. Analyze your projects to get fresh measures.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `sonar-findbugs-plugin` depends on the [xstream](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream) jar which up until sonar version < 5.0 was provided transitively by the `sonar-plugin-api`. This dependency was removed from the `sonar-plugin-api` in version 5.0 as can be seen in [SONAR-4118](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-4118).

This however was only carried out after the `sonar-findbugs-plugin` ensured it had explicitly declared its dependency on the `xstream` module (so that it now packages it within its own jar). This was handled by [SONARFBUGS-9](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARFBUGS-9) which is now available in the `sonar-findbugs-plugin` as of 2.4.

Given this, you will have to upgrade your `sonar-findbugs-plugin` to at least [2.4](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/java/sonar-findbugs-plugin/2.4/sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.4.jar) and make sure you also upgrade the `sonar-java-plugin` to [2.4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java/sonar-java-plugin/2.4) as well since findbugs 2.4 seems to require that (else findbugs will throw an exception stating that it needs it).

This should solve the error thrown by the findbugs plugin when attempting to instantiate an XStream object

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for us: 
I've upgraded SonarQube to 5.1.2. It works ok with FindBugs 3.2, but when I try to upgrade FindBugs to FindBugs 3.3 (sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar or sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.2.jar), it fails with the same error.

```
2015.09.21 10:40:14 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.xml.FindBugsFilter.createXStream(FindBugsFilter.java:157) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsProfileImporter.importProfile(FindbugsProfileImporter.java:55) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.SonarWayWithFindbugsProfile.createProfile(SonarWayWithFindbugsProfile.java:42) ~[na:na]
```